# Can't get public bucket using Ceph API

Tags: s3cmd, ceph

I create public bucket from S3 client using comand:

```
s3cmd mb s3://public_bucket --acl-public
Bucket 's3://public_bucket/' created
```

I can see this bucket from client(s3cmd ls) and from rados gw (using radosgw-admin bucket list).
But when I use the API and send the request to the server, I always get an error 404. Why is this happening? Apache, fcgi work fine.

My request:

```
GET /public-bucket?max-keys=15 HTTP/1.1
Host: ceph_gw.objectstore.com
```

Moreover, request

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ceph_gw.objectstore.com
```

give me response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 13:20:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ListAllMyBucketsResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Owner><ID>anonymous</ID><DisplayName></DisplayName></Owner><Buckets></Buckets></ListAllMyBucketsResult>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to verify is from http headers if `x-amz-acl` is set to the appropriate value that you requested. If yes then perhaps there is something wrong with the server ACL code.

You could alternatively try - https://github.com/minio/mc, which implements a console UI for http traffic.

```
$ mc --debug mb http://ceph_gw.objectstore.com/yourbucket
$ mc --debug access set public http://ceph_gw.objectstore.com/yourbucket
```

Example

```
$ mc --debug access set public s3/deflector
mc: <DEBUG> PUT /deflector?acl= HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent:  Minio/UNOFFICIAL.GOGET (mc; darwin; amd64)
Content-Length: 0
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=**REDACTED**/20151107/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=**REDACTED**
X-Amz-Acl: public-read-write
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
X-Amz-Date: 20151107T002030Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip

mc: <DEBUG> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
mc: <DEBUG> Response Time:  917.38277ms

Set access permission ‘public’ updated successfully for ‘https://s3.amazonaws.com/deflector’
```

Answer (score 0):

s3cmd (since at least 2011) has sent headers["x-amz-acl"] = "public-read" during bucket create if --acl-public is specified.  Perhaps you have an older version of s3cmd, or Ceph doesn't honor that header?

Comment: I use the newest version of s3cmd. How can I check, what headers were read?

Comment: You would have to ask in a Ceph forum or look at the Ceph source.